# Show that the function |P|: $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R^+_0}$ has a minimum

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I can't figure out the following question and I was hoping that somebody could help me. Thank you in Advance.

$P(z)$ is a non-constant polynomial with complex coefficients and is defined by $P: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$

The exercise requires me to prove the following:

(i) $\lim \limits_{z \to \infty} P(z)=\infty$

(ii) The function $|P|: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R^+_0}$ has a minimum. (Hint:Show that $|P|$ has a minimum on every closed disk and use (i) )

I have proven (i) but I don't know how to go on from there.
I know that the function in (ii), as it is taking the absolute value and the range being all positive real numbers with 0, must have a minimum, however I am confused how to use the "hint".

Comment: Didn't you mean in (i) that $\;|z|\to \infty\;$ ?

Comment: Do you know the extreme value theorem?

Comment: @DonAntonio the exercise doesn't use absolute value

Comment: Fine, @SVL . Then how did you manage to prove (i)? What does $\;z\to\infty\;$ means at all? That the real part tends to infinity, the imaginary part...both?

Comment: @DonAntonio It's a speculation, It could be that the one who writes the exercise think about $\mathbb{C}$ as a subset of the Riemann sphere (i.e. $\hat \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}\cup \{ \infty \}$ with the one point compactification topology) and so in this sense $z\rightarrow\infty$ means that $|z|\rightarrow\infty$. I just can't see any other way to interpret this.

Comment: @Yanko Well, that assumption is **now**, after the OP changed the question, pretty trivial. First, he wrote that $\;P\;$ is "a function". Then, he changed that to $\;P\;$ is a *polynomial* ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah yeah I suspected it was a polynomial because he said "complex coefficients". Indeed if it's not a polynomial then $(i)$ doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is a polynomial it is also continuous and so it has a minimum on every closed disk. Let $M$ be the minimum on the disk of radius $1$.

On the other hand you know that $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}  P(z) = \infty$ (note that as DonAntonio comment you may want to take $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ but I consider these two notions equivalent).

This means that if $z$ lies outside of a sufficiently large disk (say of radius $r$) then $|P(z)|>M$. Let $N$ be the minimum over the disk of radius $r$.

Then $\min |P(z)|$ is the minimum between three terms (The disk of radius $1$, the disk of radius $r$, and outside of the disk of radius $r$). But by the choice of $r$ the minimum can't be outside of the disk of radius $r$ and so the minimum is $\min(M,N)$.